# Assert if any of two strings are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I have a webpage with two different strings depending on time of the day - "Good day" or "Good night".

Is there any way to do some sort of `assert_content(my_string)` that check if one of the two given strings is present?

It doesn't matter which one is present, just that one is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Sebastian's answer will work as long as the page is loaded when you go to check, it loses Capybaras waiting/retrying behavior and can lead to flaky tests if used to check content while a page is changing (immediately after clicking a button, etc).

When using minitest a better solution would be to continue using the Capybara provided `assert_content` matcher but pass it a regex

```
assert_content(/Good day|Good night/)
```

If using RSpec you can do the same

```
expect(page).to have_content(/Good day|Good night/)
```

or you can write it in a potentially more readable manner

```
expect(page).to have_content('Good day').or(have_content('Good night'))
```

Comment: Nice improvement. Instead thinking in a regex and all the scenarios to cover.

Answer (score 3):

If using MiniTest then you can use `assert_match`:

```
assert_match /Good day|Good night/, string
```

If using RSpec then you can use `match`:

```
expect(string).to match /Good day|Good night/
```

Comment: What if the page contains "Good food" - wouldn't that also show as a match?

Comment: I misunderstood and you clarified me, does `Good day|Good night` fit well in this scenario?

Comment: That seems the ticket yea

Comment: Wondering the difference between `Good (day|night)` and `Good day|Good night` despite the matching groups.

Comment: What about"Good nightclubs are rare"?

Comment: Actually that's a good catch Cary.  My suggestion is that the OP actually wrap the specific string in a <span> tag with a specific ID or class, and expand the match to use that as the basis.  That can remove the chances of unintended matches like you suggest.